# not random enough for monte carlo

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I am trying to generate values from a normal distribution using a monte carlo method, as per the website http://math60082.blogspot.ca/2013/03/c-coding-random-numbers-and-monte-carlo.html

I modified the code a bit from the original so it calculates the variance and mean for the numbers generated directly to check if the method is working rather than do the tests separately (same difference really but just a heads up).

**Question**

Regardless of what I do, the variance is way above 1 and the mean is not zero. Is it possible the pseudo-random numbers generated aren't random enough?

**Code**

**PLEASE NOTE THAT THE AUTHOR OF THE ABOVE GIVEN WEBSITE IS THE PERSON WHO WROTE THE CODE**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// return a uniformly distributed random number
double uniformRandom()
{
    return ( (double)(rand()) + 1. )/( (double)(RAND_MAX) + 1. );
}

// return a normally distributed random number
double normalRandom()
{
    double u1=uniformRandom();
    double u2=uniformRandom();
    return cos(8.*atan(1.)*u2)*sqrt(-2.*log(u1)); 
}

int main()
{
    double z;
    int N=1000;
    double array[N];
    double mean=0 ,variance=0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        z=normalRandom();
        cout << i << "->"<< z<< endl;
        mean+=z;
        array[i]=z;
    }

    mean=mean/N ;
    cout << " mean = " << mean << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        variance = variance + (mean - array[i])*(mean - array[i]);
    }
    variance = variance/N;
    cout << " variance = " << variance << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Apparently as pointed by users, I screwed up and  the program was not working because of a very silly mistake.

Comment: I've read in the past that generating a normal distribution random from a uniform random is generally not particularly accurate -- better to use a normal distribution RNG.  (Dunno exactly where to find one, though.  Used to be one in the old standard Fortran libs, but don't know about C++.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I don't know where you read that but that's a very shaky statement. Generation of normal distributions form a uniform distribution is quite a [common](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) [thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform). *However*, using a poor uniform generator (like `rand()`) will lead to a poor normal distribution.

Comment: @HotLicks Noted, apparently the friend I am doing this for, wants it to be a monte carlo method.

Comment: @MikeBantegui -- Like I said, this was "in the past" -- several decades ago, I'm thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seems computed the `mean` in a wrong way. `mean` should be averaged over `N`, while you only sum over all array elements. current `mean` is actually `sum`.

```
mean = mean /N
```

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.BUt the variance is still  nowhere near 1.

Comment: @nerorevenge you may try to generate more than 2000 rand numbers and see whether the variance is getting closer to 1? the rand() may not be a good random number generator (just my wild guess).

Comment: @nerorevenge: you're wrong. the incorrect value of the mean affects the value of the variance. after you fix the value of the mean, that fixes all the problems in your code.

Comment: @nerorevenge Standard deviation should be 1, not Variance. Std. Dev = square root of variance.

Comment: @iValueValue does it matter? (not for just this case, but for any case)

Comment: @iValueValue: By definition, if `standard deviation = 1` then `variance = 1` because `sqrt(1) = 1` and `1 * 1 = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

`rand()` is a very low quality random numbers generator in most implementations. Some Linux versions would take value from kernel entropy pool, but it is not guaranteed across platforms (e.g. on Windows?) Use a Mersenne Twister instead. Boost libraries implement one.

EDIT: taocp answer highlights a coding problem, but the RNG issue still applies.

Comment: Noted, and the code is being run on a linux machine ,so your answer could be right, let me get gback to you.

Comment: Gback? Anyway, not all Linux libc do actually use the entropy pool. I cannot tell which do and which do not, but I'm pretty sure `rand` is good for playing "guess my number" against the PC, not for doing statistical analysis or cryptography.

Comment: You don't need boost for this if you're using an up to date version of gcc. `<random>` has all of this functionality now.